# How to export PDF from page.html with css DomPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

actually i'm using domPDF to print pages into PDFs
the issue is all the PDF i've print from externe pages ,has no CSS

this an exemple :

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$html = file_get_contents('page.html');

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream();
```

The page.html has links of bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJnzK.png)

**Question :**

How to add external url with their css ?
I do not know if this is even possible. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: there should be no problem for this, at least if the CSS is linked in the HTML file, DomPDF will load that CSS

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia check this , this the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJnzK.png

Comment: please post the HTML source of that page on the question

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the problem it's not in the page , i've print a lot of externe files ,and urls , and the same issue

Comment: maybe is your connection that is blocking that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution is quite simply, the domPDF vs TCPDF or FPDF is using their own styling, so css is not recognized in domPDF you have to design your own styling using domPDF functions

for line color :

```
$this->SetFillColor(218,218,218);
```

For text color :

```
$this->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
```